increase react ag grid floating filter popup width
I have used the following css but it increases the width of all the floating filters. I have searched the web and stack overflows still i was not able to fi it. Can anyone help?
.ag-tabs.ag-menu.ag-focus-managed.ag-ltr.ag-popup-child { width: 400px !important; } 
I want only one specific filter popup width to be increased

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

{
colId: "issueTypeIDIdentifierText",
field: "issueTypeIDIdentifierText",
headerName: "Issue Type",
filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
width: 320,
  },


Try to add a specific id or class to your component if possible, then wrap your custom css:


.myDiv {
  color: red
}

#myId.myDiv {
    color: green
  }
<div  class="myDiv">test 1</div>
<div  class="myDiv">test 2</div>
<div id="myId" class="myDiv common-class">test 3</div>




I am using ag grid built in filters. I can't add custom ids.

Are you using this component (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-floating-filter/#floating-filter-props) There's no custom props to customize yuor item?

No, I didn't find any props.
